# Google Chromebook / Chromebook Kiosk mode - does the browser/app run in incognito mode? Does it accept cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, kiosk, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I have successfully set up a Chromebook on Kiosk mode, however the app don't seem to remember my login details via cookies.

i.e. if I click on "Remember me" on the webpage after I enter my username and password, it will not remember it next time it boots.

I'm assuming this is a cookie issue, the question is that does Kiosk mode have permission to store cookies so I won't need to log in next time?

**To clarify**: Remember me as in cookies and not Chrome storing my username and password.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about kiosk session on a managed Chromebook, or a Chrome kiosk app that you've written, or something else? Some more detail will be helpful.